# Why hide Naruto's identity?

Tags: naruto

What harm would come if Naruto was told the fact about his lineage?

Why didn't they just hide the fact that Naruto was a Jinchuuriki to save him from the outcast treatment from the villagers during his childhood?

Comment: How far in the Naruto story are you? As this is explained quite detailed further in the story, an explanation might spoil you.

Comment: well, the ninja war is going on, where the beasts are ripped off obito

Answer (score 5):

Short answer.

Naruto's dad, Minato Namikaze (aka Fourth Hokage), was a famous ninja and, of course, had a lot of enemies, and if his enemies knew his son's identity they would go after him.

> Orphaned, Naruto grew up not knowing who his parents were, receiving only his mother's surname, as Hiruzen wanted to **protect Naruto from his father's enemies**.

Yes, they could have just told Naruto his parents identity, but since the villagers hated him he might think that the only way to stop their hatred is by telling them his parents identity. Which would then lead to the spreading of the word and people hunting him down.

Sources:

- [Naruto Uzumaki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto_Uzumaki])